# Java XML node RegEx string manipulation - Return node content variably, excluding the closing tag

Tags: java, regex, xml, group

In the following Java code, I was forced to use a substring on the returned content because I (claude.ai) could not concisely figure out what regex parameter to exclude the ">" from the starting xml node.  How do we accomplish that?  The goal was to receive an xml document, and iterate through very specific tags, and swap out oddball characters that cause issues in certain platforms.  It is currently working now, as tested on [Java sandbox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php), but I'd like to know how to do it so I would not have to use the substring method.  If you're up to it, please also expound upon what each part of the regular expression is doing.  To reproduce the issue, simply remove `".substring(1); //Bandaid fix because I don't know regex"` with `";"`.  The Tag content console log will start with a `">"`, this is what I don't' want.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        String xml = "<Description>–%%%%%%%%%%%%%130609 & -++ %% Cracker Craze––+/()</Description><Value code='1'>Triscuit Lapsed --Buyers</Value>";
        //String xml = "<Description>–%%%%%%%%%%%%%130609 & -++ %% Cracker Craze––+/()</Description><Value>Triscuit Lapsed --Buyers</Value>";

        // Mapping of characters to replacements
        String[][] replacements = {
            {"-", "HYPHEN"},
            {"–", "LONG.HYPHEN"},
            {"‘", "SMART.QUOTE.A"},
            {"’", "SMART.QUOTE.B"},
            {"“", "D.SMART.QUOTE.A"},
            {"”", "D.SMART.QUOTE.B"},
            {"+", "PLUS"},
            {"%", "PERCENT"},
            {"&", "AND"},
            {"(", "OPEN.PARENTHESIS"},
            {")", "CLOSE.PARENTHESIS"},
            {"/", "FORWARD.SLASH"},
            {"\\\\", "BACK.SLASH"}
        };

        // Compile regex pattern
        String pattern = "<(Description|Value)(?: (\\b[^>]*))?([^<]*?)</\\1>"; //Stable working

        Pattern targetXMLTags = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        // Find all XML node tags
        Matcher matcher = targetXMLTags.matcher(xml);

        // String buffer to build output
        StringBuffer processBufferXML = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {

            String tag = matcher.group(1);
            String tagAttributes = null;

            String content = matcher.group(3).substring(1); //Bandaid fix because I don't know regex

            if(matcher.group(2) != null) {
                tagAttributes = matcher.group(2);
            }

            System.out.println("Match found: " + matcher.toString());
            System.out.println("Tag name: " + tag);
            System.out.println("Tag attribute: " + tagAttributes);
            System.out.println("Tag content: " + content);

            for (String[] replacement : replacements) {
                content = content.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);
            }

            if(tagAttributes != null) {
                matcher.appendReplacement(processBufferXML, "<" + tag + " " + tagAttributes + ">" + content + "</" + tag + ">");

            } else {
                matcher.appendReplacement(processBufferXML, "<" + tag + ">" + content + "</" + tag + ">");
            }

        }

        matcher.appendTail(processBufferXML);

        System.out.println("Replaced XML: " + processBufferXML.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you paste your regex into [regex101](https://regex101.com/) it will generate step-by-step explanation.

Comment: You should never use Regex on XML.  Regex is regular expressions and xml is not regular.

Comment: @jdweng may you recommend a more sound approach in Java with the platform being Talend and the file received is a raw XML file.

Comment: Always parse XML using a real XML parser, not a hand-crafted regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *capture pattern*.

```
(?i)<(description|value)\s*(.*?)>(.*?)</\1\s*>
```